# Sorting one file based on the order of another file in awk

Tags: file, sorting, awk

I have the following files:
f1.txt:

```
1 1  
1 2   
3 3   
3 4   
2 5  
2 6
```

f2.txt:

```
1  
2   
3
```

I want to sort f1.txt according to f2.txt first column match, expected output is below

```
1 1  
1 2   
2 5   
2 6  
3 3  
3 4
```

I tried something like

```
awk '{if(NR==FNR) {a[$1]=$0} else {b[$1]=$0} for(i in b) print a[i]}' f2.txt f1.txt
```

But the results I'm getting are not what I expected.

Appreciate if someone can help

Comment: Take a look at [how to format my code block](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Please no links to files or screenshots of code or data.

Comment: The output depends only on the `b` array, and the `b` array is filled by code that depends only on the contents of the second file, `f1.txt`.

Comment: I apologize, my previous question was a mess, I think it's clearer now.

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '
    FNR==NR { a[NR]=$1; next }
    { b[$1] = (b[$1] ? b[$1]"\n" $0 : $0) }
    END{ for (i=1; i<=length(a); i++) print b[a[i]] }
' f2.txt f1.txt 

1 1  
1 2
2 5
2 6
3 3
3 4
```

Answer (score 3):

Generalising @ufopilot's answer to handle non-numbers:

```
awk '
    FNR==NR { a[++i]=$1; next }
    { b[$1] = b[$1] $0 RS }
    END { ORS=""; for (j=1; j<=i; j++) print b[a[j]] }
' f2.txt f1.txt
```

Note that if `f2.txt` has duplicated entries, corresponding lines will also be printed multiple times. If that is not desired, clear `b[a[j]]` after it is first printed.

---

If `f1.txt` is too big to fit in memory but `f2.txt` will fit comfortably, then you can decorate the lines using `awk`, then use `sort` to reorder, then `cut` off the extra column:

```
awk '
    FNR==NR { o[$1]=++i; next }
    { print o[$1] "\t" $0 }
' f2.txt f1.txt |
sort -s -n -k1,1 |
cut -f 2-
```

In this version, if `f2.txt` contains duplicated entries, only the final duplicate is used. So

```
1
3
2
3
```

will be treated as:

```
1
2
3
```

---

Reformating your code:

```
awk '
    {
        if (NR==FNR) {
            a[$1]=$0
        } else {
            b[$1]=$0
        }
        for (i in b) print a[i]
    }
' f2.txt f1.txt
```

There are several issues.

- `for (i in b)` can return elements of `b` in arbitrary order (`gawk` should return a repeatable ordering, but POSIX-standard `awk` may not)
- you should be doing `for (i in a)` anyway (otherwise you are ignoring the `f2.txt` ordering entirely)
- `print a[i]` tries to print lines from `f2.txt` but you want lines from `f1.txt`
- you overwrite `b[i]` when you should append to it
- the `for` loop runs for every line but should only run at the end

Applying fixes for these issues might give:

```
gawk '
    {
        if (NR==FNR) {
            a[$1]
        } else {
            b[$1] = b[$1] $0 RS
        }
    }
    END {
        for (i in a) print b[i]
    }
' f2.txt f1.txt
```

gives:

```
1 1
1 2

2 5
2 6

3 3
3 4
```

but would give completely different order with some other `awk` implementations.

My code addresses these remaining issues by:

- altering the assignment to `a` so that elements can be ordered (`a[++i]=$1`)
- replacing `for (i in a)` by a guaranteed ordering
- redefining `ORS` so the blank lines don't appear

To be safer, my code should check if `b[a[j]]` exists before printing it:

```
if (a[j] in b) print b[a[j]]
```

If `b[a[j]]` does not exist (ie. `f2.txt` contains a value not in `f1.txt`), my script creates an empty element in `b`. Although this prints as nothing and so is not a problem here, in other scripts adding an extra element like this can introduce subtle bugs.

Comment: The `-s` option to `sort` performs "stable sorting".  Not all versions of `sort` provide this option.

Comment: Ok, i removed mine.

Comment: @ufopilot why? it answered the question perfectly well

Comment: But yours too.. And the nice explanation ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much jhnc, the answer works perfectly well, also many thanks for the comprehensive explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk -v ORS= '
    NR==FNR { a[$1] = a[$1] $0 RS; next }
    { print a[$1] }
' f1.txt f2.txt
1 1
1 2
2 5
2 6
3 3
3 4
```